Permiso denegado al tratar de arrancar postgresql con docker
Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que trabajo en dos ordenadores distintos, un windows 10 de sobremesa y un linux mint como protatil.
En windows hice un archivo docker-compose.yml para poder generar una imagen de postgres para almacenar mi base de datos, y no tengo mayor problema.
Ahora viene cuando hice un git pull en mi linux y se descargó el proyecto, una vez le fui a dar de nuevo al comando docker compose up comenzaron a saltar errores.
Borré todas las imágenes que tenía en docker, todos los volúmenes y traté de volver a lanzarlo sin resultado.
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:15.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

El log que me está saliendo repetido en bucle es el siguiente:
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container p-qfoil-postgres-db-1  Created                                                                                                                                   0.1s 
Attaching to postgres-db-1
postgres-db-1  | chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
postgres-db-1  | find: ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: Permission denied
postgres-db-1  | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
postgres-db-1 exited with code 1

Y he aquí imágenes del resultado:

Otra forma de hacerlo que probé fue añadiendo sudo para dar permisos, en mi cabeza tenía sentido:
[sudo] contraseña para aquintanal:               
Attaching to postgres-db-1
postgres-db-1 exited with code 1
postgres-db-1  | 
postgres-db-1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres-db-1  | 
postgres-db-1  | 2024-04-20 08:55:26.358 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_notify": No such file or directory
postgres-db-1  | 2024-04-20 08:55:26.359 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres-db-1 exited with code 1

Y aquí tengo los permisos otorgador en el proyecto:
drwxrwxr-x  10 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr 19 22:24 .
drwxrwxr-x   3 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr  5 22:53 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    290 abr 20 10:38 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    147 abr 19 22:24 .env
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    129 abr 19 22:24 .env.template
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal     40 abr  5 22:53 .eslintrc.json
drwxrwxr-x   8 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr 19 22:24 .git
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    391 abr  5 22:53 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x   6 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr 13 13:13 .next
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal     92 abr  5 22:53 next.config.mjs
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    201 abr  5 22:54 next-env.d.ts
drwxrwxr-x 377 aquintanal aquintanal  16384 abr 19 23:11 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    945 abr 19 22:24 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal 222839 abr 19 23:11 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal     83 abr  5 22:53 postcss.config.js
drwx------  10        999 aquintanal   4096 abr 20 10:57 postgres
drwxrwxr-x   3 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr 19 22:24 prisma
drwxrwxr-x   3 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr  8 22:51 public
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal   1383 abr  5 22:53 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  13 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr 19 22:24 src
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    531 abr  5 22:53 tailwind.config.ts
-rw-rw-r--   1 aquintanal aquintanal    578 abr  5 22:53 tsconfig.json
drwxrwxr-x   2 aquintanal aquintanal   4096 abr  5 22:53 .vscode

¿Por qué me pasa esto en linux y en windows no?

EDIT
A raíz de una de las respuestas me veo obligado a poner que no se crea ningún volumen cuando se instancia docker:

De hecho, ahora mismo está así nada más iniciar:



Para este caso una de la mejores alternativas es crear y hacer referencia a los volume que maneja docker, sin la necesidad crear directorios en tu maquina host, para ello modifica tu docker-compose.yml, para que quede de la siguiente manera.
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:15.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - "data:/var/lib/postgresql/data" #hacemos referencia al volume
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes: #creamos el volume
  data:

Puedes verificar el volume creado a travez del docker-compose.yml con este comando:
docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     stackoverflow_data

Con esto tus datos serán persistentes.

Edito la pregunta porque no se crea ningún volumen :/
